# While creating an object what does left side class indicates and right side class indicates?

Tags: java, class, jsp, private, public

I am having this doubt from so long so finally asking here. Let me give you an example.

```
class A{
void run(){
System.out.println("hi");
}
}
class B extends A{
void jump(){
}
}

public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
A a = new A();  //statement 1

A a1= new B(); //statement 2
B b= (B) new A(); // statement 3

a.run();
b.run();

b.jump();
}};
```

Now my basic doubt is what is the difference between statement1,2,3? please someone explain me.

Comment: If you try to compile this, you will see one major difference with statement 3...

Comment: A cannot be cast to B ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Now my basic doubt is what is the difference between statement 1,2,3?
>
> `A a = new A();  //statement 1`

The bit to the right of the `=` creates an object of class `A`; the bit to the left defines the variable to store it in, in this case a variable of type `A`; the `=` is an assignment. So this creates an object of class `A` and saves the reference to it in a variable of type `A`.

> `A a1= new B(); //statement 2`

The bit to the right of the `=` creates an object of class `B`; the bit to the left defines the variable to store it in, in this case a variable of type `A`; the `=` is an assignment. So this creates an object of class `B` and saves the reference to it in a variable of type `A`. This means that when accessing the object through that variable, you only have access to the things defined by `A`, even though the object is a `B`. So for example, even though `B` has a `jump` method, you cannot do this:

```
a1.jump(); // Compile-time error
```

> `B b= (B) new A(); // statement 3`

Will fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException` because you're trying to store an `A` in a variable of type `B`. You can't assign `A` instances to `B` variables. You can only assign instances to variables if they are *assignment-compatible*, which in practice means:

1. The variable is a class type and the object is the same type (your statement 1)
2. The variable is a class type and the object's type is a *subclass* of that type (your statement 2)
3. The variable is an interface type and the object implements that interface
4. The variable is an interface type and the object implements a *sub-interface* of that interface

Comment: Thanks for the explanation my doubt is what left side class indicates and what right side class indicates?

Answer (score 2):

TJ's answer is very good and verbose, just to add to your original question. The left side of the '=' is the reference to the actual object on right side.

Think it like this, the left side is an address of a 'house', while right side is the actual physical 'house'.

In the third statement, you are pretty sure that the the house `'A' is a house 'B'` and then trying to cast it. Compiler will trust you, but runtime control may fail, if your assumption is not right (here, it looks like that at runtime, it will throw  ClassCastEsception)

Also, another difference is that the address in the code reside on stack, while right side resides on heap area of memory.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues that are getting confused here, the type of a variable or expression, and the class of an object.

Each object has a class that is established when it is created through "new" or clone(). That class is fixed for the lifetime of the object.

An reference variable or expression is either null or a pointer to some object. The type of a reference variable is indicated by the name of a class or interface. It can only reference a object if the class of the object matches or extends, directly or indirectly, the class, or implements the interface. In effect, the type of the variable guarantees that the object has the corresponding members.

```
A a = new A();  //statement 1
```

Declares a variable "a" with type A, meaning it can only be null or a pointer to an A, or an object whose class extends A. Initializes it as a pointer to a newly created object of class A.

```
A a1= new B(); //statement 2
```

Declares a variable "a1" with type A, meaning it can only be null or a pointer to an A, or an object whose class extends A. Initializes it with a pointer to a newly created B. Since B extends A, the conversion of a type B expression to type A is permitted.

```
B b= (B) new A(); // statement 3
```

The difference here is that A does not extend B. A type A reference can be cast to type B if, and only if, it is null or a pointer to an object of class B, or a class that extends B. Class A does not extend B. The compiler will accept this, because the cast claims that "new A()" is null or refers to a class B object, or an object of a class extending B. It will get a ClassCastException at run time, because that claim is false.

The type of a reference variable or expression is determined at compile time. In the course of a program run, it may be null or refer to objects of several different classes, but only class that are appropriate for its declared type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand more about Polymorphism, which is the ability of an object to take on many forms.
see:
[Java polymorphism creating a subclass object using its superclass variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774403/java-polymorphism-creating-a-subclass-object-using-its-superclass-variable)
or:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)