# Do following conditions achieves Polymorphism?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

What I know is polymorphism is one name many form, which can be achieved using overloading and overriding where two or many methods has same name (forget about prototype for now).
This is clear for me.
1-But having super class reference pointing to sub class object without any overridden method is also polymorphism?
2-Having Interface reference pointing to its implementation class object is also polymorphism?

I read somewhere that this is object polymorphism. Is it true?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13774403/2830834

Comment: I, for one, have never figured out why so many programmers get so hung up about the dreams of parrots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymorphism is the ability of an object to take on many forms. The most common use of polymorphism in OOP occurs when a parent class reference is used to refer to a child class object.x

Any Java object that can pass more than one IS-A test is considered to be polymorphic. In Java, all Java objects are polymorphic since any object will pass the IS-A test for their own type and for the class Object.

An object implementing an interface can be assigned to a reference variable typed to the interface.
Interface also provides polymorphism in java

Comment: means interface achieves polymorphism?

Comment: @nilesh Yes having an interface DOES IN FACT achieve polymorphism. The reason is that you can implement ("use:) an interface in many different classes and by doing this you can achieve many different forms. You can use an interface to alter the default behaviors for a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

having super class reference pointing to sub class object without any overridden method is also polymorphism?
Yes.Technically this is called as upcasting.

Having Interface reference pointing to its implementation class object is also polymorphism?
Yes.Polymorphism allows you define one interface and have multiple implementation.